# I want to display a page after getting data from api with Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

There is a website with multiple pages in Nuxt.js.
I want to first fetch the content of all pages with api and then display the pages.

So I fetched them with plugins first.

```
//plugins/fetchApi.ts
export default defineNuxtPlugin(async () => {
  const store = useStore();
  const apiData:any = await $fetch('https://test-api.com');
  store.data = apiData
 })
```

I want to display the `index.vue` after this fetch is done,
but how do I tell `index.vue` that the fetch is done?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution myself.

I made the mistake of using store.
Using useState was the right thing to do!

Thank you very much.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: OK
I just changed store to useState, so the code looks like this  
  
`export default defineNuxtPlugin(async () => {  
  const { projectData, updateProject } = useProject();  
  const apiData:any = await $fetch('https://test-api.com');  
  updateProject(apiData)  
  // console.log(projectData.value)  
 })`

Comment: I couldn't break lines. I have to ask a new question to comment...